# Is it a bad practice to use font icons in native android apps?

Tags: android, font-awesome

I am going to use font icons instead of pngs in my native android app. I cant find any recommendation to use or not to use font icons.

So is it a bad practice or a good one to use font icons in native android apps?

(By native i mean i don't use webview for user interface)

Comment: It's a good practice. Using font icons has been a good alternative to SVGs (since a font icon is an SVG itself, but it uses the font functionality instead). SVG support has only gotten better recently, but I don't know how good it is now, or how backwards-compatible it is. Font icons work well, even for native java applications. I don't see any reason not to use them.

Comment: You are free to use them, you can create your own icons.

Answer (score 6):

As any other practice in the world, it has its own **pros** and **cons**.

**Pros**:

- changing colour of the icon becomes super-easy fix
- since font icons are SVGs, they scale without visual artefacts (comparing to scaling small .png)
- icon-font takes less space, than same number of icons stored as .png's

**Cons:**

- It's pretty inflexible, unless you can edit font and add new elements by yourself.
- It's not readable:

  ```
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="\uE118"/>
  ```

  `\uE118` and other unicodes are barely something you can keep in memory
- You're forced to use custom typefaces everywhere you use icons, which leads to  spaghetti code:

  - all TextViews should have ids
  - you set Typefaces everywhere in the code-behind

    (or, as I did, extend `TextView` class and setting Typeface based on the custom string attribute(with font path) you're passing in the xml)
- You'd be surprise, how often people, who generate the fonts for you, change icons' codes. As a result, you can get pretty bizarre effects

**My personal observation:**
png's are better for prototyping, for building up something fast; icon-fonts are better, once you develop production-quality, stable from design perspective application.